# Разбить строку на отдельные слова списком

Tags: c, struct

Есть строка и её нужно разбить на слова
списком. Вот структура для списка:

```
struct wos{
    char *word;
    struct wos *next;
}
```

Как это можно грамотно реализовать? Нужно ли, например, сразу в условный буфер прочитать строку и работать с ней? Или посимвольно читать и через свитчи обрабатывать?

Разделитель пробел или табуляция. Кодом ответ не нужен, хотя бы с чего начать. Далее разделение будет включать ещё и учитывание пробелов в составе слова и т.д. То есть с помощью спец символов можно будет записать в одно звено списка что-то вроде "asd fg". Но сейчас мне требуется грамотное начало для разбиения строки просто на слова.
Желательно без использования string.h и  точно никакого ++ кода.

Comment: Это учебная задача. Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос ваш код, решающий задачу. Без этого мы не продвинемся.

Comment: Можно считать всю строку, можно посимвольно. Можно и через свитчи :) Можно (но я так понял, запрещено преподавателем) через `strtok`. С чего начать? С написания какого-то из вариантов. Это не та задача, в которой вы можете затратить неделю работы, чтобы потом понять, что пошли не тем путем. Просто начинайте реализовывать какой-то из вариантов, а дальше работа сама покажет.

Comment: @Harry, это будет в итоге командный интерпретатор, задача просто разделена на много частей, это начало :D так что возможно неделю все таки займёт)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, код начальный ни к чему, варианты которые вижу я описал, просто не совсем понимаю какой выбирать для дальнейшего расширения ))

Comment: Я говорю не о всей задаче, а о конкретном разборе строки на слова.